# Trying to turn on 4 leds in arduino with yii but it only turns led #1

Tags: php, arduino, yii2, arduino-esp8266

I'm writing a code where I will be able to turn on 4 arduino leds via wifi, the issue I have is that it only turn on led #1 when I'm trying to turn on led #2, I've checked the code and it should be correct as to how its written but I can't find the reason as to why it doesn't work

I've tried changing the conditions on the ifs to see if it detects them, say I change in the code that it should find pin 5 when it should be pin 4, if I try to turn on pin #4 with that condition, it will still turn on pin #1

**Note:** the if and else if I've changed how they're written and everything but the result is still the same, led #1 is the only one that will turn on

```
public function actionEncender($id,$pin)
{

   *if*($pin = 1)
   {
    $equipo = Equipos::find()->where(['id'=>$id])->one();
    $equipo->estado = '1';
    $equipo->save ();

    $curl = new curl\Curl();

    $response = $curl->get($equipo->ip.'/gpio/LEDa=ON');

    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $id]);
}
elseif ($pin = 2)
{
    $equipo = Equipos::find()->where(['id'=>$id])->two();
    $equipo->estado = '1';
    $equipo->save ();

    $curl = new curl\Curl();

    $response = $curl->get($equipo->ip.'/gpio/LEDb=ON');

    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $id]);
}

elseif ($pin = '3')
{
    $equipo = Equipos::find()->where(['id'=>$id])->three();
    $equipo->estado = '1';
    $equipo->save ();

    $curl = new curl\Curl();

    $response = $curl->get($equipo->ip.'/gpio/LEDc=ON');

    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $id]);
}
elseif ($pin = '4')
{
    $equipo = Equipos::find()->where(['id'=>$id])->four();
    $equipo->estado = '1';
    $equipo->save ();

    $curl = new curl\Curl();

    $response = $curl->get($equipo->ip.'/gpio/LEDd=ON');

    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $id]);
}
}

public function actionApagar($id, $pin)
{
if ($pin = '1')
    {
    $equipo = Equipos::find()->where(['id'=>$id])->one();
    $equipo->estado = '0';
    $equipo->save ();

    $curl = new curl\Curl();

    $response = $curl->get($equipo->ip.'/gpio/LEDa=OFF');

    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $id]);
}

if ($pin = '2')
{
    $equipo = Equipos::find()->where(['id'=>$id])->two();
    $equipo->estado = '0';
    $equipo->save ();

    $curl = new curl\Curl();

    $response = $curl->get($equipo->ip.'/gpio/LEDb=OFF');

    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $id]);
}

if ($pin = '3')
{
    $equipo = Equipos::find()->where(['id'=>$id])->three();
    $equipo->estado = '0';
    $equipo->save ();

    $curl = new curl\Curl();

    $response = $curl->get($equipo->ip.'/gpio/LEDc=OFF');

    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $id]);
}

if ($pin = '4')
{
    $equipo = Equipos::find()->where(['id'=>$id])->four();
    $equipo->estado = '0';
    $equipo->save ();

    $curl = new curl\Curl();

    $response = $curl->get($equipo->ip.'/gpio/LEDd=OFF');

    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $id]);
}
}
```

Comment: Use `==` for comparison; `=` assigns the value on the right to the variable on the left.

Comment: made the change, still didn't work :/

Comment: Actually when I made the change an error popped up: Calling unknown method: yii\db\ActiveQuery::two(), sorry if its complicated, not really into programming

Comment: As the @ChrisWhite said, you must convert all the bets to **`==`**.  Because when, for example, `$pin = 1`, the pin is in all conditions equal to 1(other conditions are **not checked**). Then when you change to `==`, you have another problem in your **ActiveQuery class** (`two ()`)

Comment: Thanks for the help, it was indeed ==, just had another problem with the functions which I was able to fix, sorry for the late response but I appreciate all of the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refactored your code and corrected logical errors.

```
private function loadModel($id)
{
    $equipo = Equipos::findOne((int)$id);
    if ($equipo === null) {
        throw new \yii\web\HttpException('Pin #' . $id . ' not found');
    }

    return $equipo;
}

public function actionEncender ($id)
{
    $equipo = $this->loadModel($id);
    $equipo->estado = 1;
    if (!$equipo->save(false, ['estado'])) {
        throw new \yii\web\HttpException('Error during save estado state');
    }

    $curl = new curl\Curl();
    $response = $curl->get($equipo->ip.'/gpio/LEDa=ON');

    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $id]);
}

public function actionApagar($id)
{
    $equipo = $this->loadModel($id);
    $equipo->estado = 0;
    if (!$equipo->save(false, ['estado'])) {
        throw new \yii\web\HttpException('Error during save estado state');
    }

    $curl = new curl\Curl();
    $response = $curl->get($equipo->ip.'/gpio/LEDa=OFF');


    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $id]);
}
```